# What can I do to speed up Behat tests on a Selenium CI server?

Tags: php, firefox, selenium, continuous-integration, behat

I've set Jenkins up as a CI server, and have a suite of Behat tests running. However, they take an age to complete.

I am using RHEL6 and have Selenium, Firefox, Xvfb running with default config. I'm assuming that some stuff can be adjusted (more memory allocated?), but no idea what to try tweaking. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

yes more memory need to be allocated and if possible,
if possible  set JVM related parameters while starting Jenkins like for garbage collection;
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html